# How can I calculate minimum payment on quick loan?

Tags: loans, calculation

I am working on calculator for quick loans. Client can select how much he will pay monthly. Base on it payment schedule will be calculated. Payment interest depends on 1 payment period. Number of payments is limited. How can I calculate what is a minimum monthly payment if I know that number of payments should be 5, amount of loan is 250, APR is 70% and payment periods are next:

- 1 payment - 9 days,
- 2 payment - 30 days
- 3 payment - 28 days
- 4 payment - 30 days
- 5 payment - 32 days

Is it possible to calculate minimum based on this logic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APR is 70%, compounded monthly (assumed).  First convert to [effective annual rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation)

```
ear = (1 + 0.7/12)^12 - 1 = 0.9746 = 97.46 %
```

The term of the loan is 129 days, so the interest rate for the term is

```
i = (1 + ear)^(129/365) - 1 = 0.2718 = 27.18 %
```

The log rate is

```
r = ln(1 + i) = 0.2405
```

Without any repayments the amount owed at the end of the loan term would be

```
250 e^r = 317.955
```

which can also be calculated from

```
250 (1 + i) = 317.955
```

For equal payments

```
-250 e^r + p e^((120/129)r) + p e^((90/129)r) + p e^((62/129)r) + p e^((32/129)r) + p = 0
```

therefore `-317.955 + 5.61728 p = 0`

therefore `p = 56.6031`

giving a total cost of loan of `5 * 56.6031 = 283.015`

However, if the payments do not have to be equal, the cost of the loan can be minimised by paying it all off in the first installment

```
-250 e^r + p e^((120/129)r) = 0
```

giving a single repayment on day 9 of `p = 254.229`

**Check**

The daily rate is

```
d = (1 + ear)^(1/365) - 1 = 0.0018657 = 0.18657 %
```

Cost of loan paid off after 9 days is `250 (1 + d)^9 = 254.229`